# Adding LOGGING field to settings.py causes "Not Found: /" every page load

Tags: python, django, logging

```
c:\Dev>django-admin startproject mysite
```

Add the following (copied from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/) to c:\Dev\mysite\mysite\settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'c:/Dev/mysite/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Migrate, run the dev server, and visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in the browser:

```
c:\Dev>cd mysite
c:\Dev\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK

c:\Dev\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 21, 2015 - 15:52:25
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /
[21/Sep/2015 15:52:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767
```

Why am I getting `Not Found: /` every page load?

- The log file at `c:\Dev\mysite\debug.log` contains `Not Found: /` as well.
- Removing the LOGGING lines from settings.py resolves the issue.
- The standard "It worked!" page itself loads fine with a proper GET 200.

Comment: Erm, but that's right isn't it? You haven't defined any urls yet, so the page is not found. Django intercepts the 404 to show the It worked page, but it's still true.

Comment: Perhaps you have unapplied migrations and your app may not work properly until they are applied? May be it is a good idea to fix all warnings before reaching for support.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If I remove the LOGGING lines, I don't get `Not Found: /`.  In fact, if you look closely, I have a clean `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200` in the shell.

Comment: @PauloScardine Applying migrations does not affect this issue.

Comment: Even if it has nothing to do with your problem, it may look kind of sloppy and diminishes the value of your question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @PauloScardine I didn't mention migrations because I've already run them and they had no effect in relation to this particular issue.  I'll edit that into the post.

Comment: I can't catch anything wrong with your setup. If you have a Linux VM around, try to run your project there in order to check if it is something specific to Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"Not Found: /"` is being logged by code in `django.core.handlers.base.py` (in the `BaseHandler.get_response` method). You wouldn't see if you didn't configure logging, but will see it if you *do* configure logging and *don't* have a handler for the '/' URL in your urlconfs.

The 200 you see in the log output is because Django handled the 404 case with a default response.

Comment: Ah thanks.  So @DanielRoseman was correct, there's no real '/' endpoint so it's a 404.  I was just thrown off by the subsequent 200 response.